# How come default tiles don't work on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I've installed Win8 yesterday, looks cool but only Desktop and programs pins (like my installed games, office, etc) are working. Those default by Windows 8 like Games, Video, Picture, Finance, Weather, etc. are not working at all. It open the logo in full screen and then comes back to the start interface.

Do anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Avast, uninstall it and wait for edition 2013. Else, try reinstalling the apps. If that doesn't work open a command prompt with administrator priviliges and type

```
sfc /scannow
```

Tell us what output you get with this

Press

```
Win + X
```

for this menu

[image]

Comment: Avast is causing this? Are you sure?

Comment: You have Avast? Then remove it and wait for 2013 edition. Many people have reported that uninstalling avast works

Comment: Damn you were right. Working after uninstall. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear! Avast is a common issue for many. I have the same issue as yours but I am not on Avast. So, I'm stuck for now. Little hesitant to do a refresh

Answer (score 2):

There have been a few different reasons for metro apps not working.

1. Your resolution must be 1024×768 or above, you can check this by right-clicking your desktop and selecting *Screen resolution*. If it is under 1024×786 then see if you can change it by selecting options from the drop-down box, if not then unfortunately you won't be able to run metro icons.
2. Have you disabled UAC? There have been some problems reported with metro apps not working when you disable UAC. You can check by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, typing in **UAC** and the option to check should come up. Make sure you have set the option to **Default**.
3. Do you have a local or Microsoft account? There have been some problems when using Microsoft accounts, try adding a local account and testing them out there.
4. Do you have Avast Antivirus installed? This currently can cause problems with Windows 8 and if you want tiles to work again you will have to uninstall and wait for an official update from Avast.
5. If none of these work, you can try [Repairing your Windows 8 installation](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-windows-8).

Comment: None of it worked and UAC is not even installed and cannot find it on Win8 install. Guess I'll have to reinstall but the thing is it's a download and upgrade from Win 7. Where I can find the ISO and bootable version ?

Comment: Where I previously had Win + R, I have changed it to Win + W. Please try that, I made a mistake there.

Comment: I have this issue on many computers very often. Even after clean reinstall.. windows 8.1 totally disappoint me

Answer (score 2):

I reckon free antiviruses downloaded and installed are the cause of these problems.

- uninstall Avast
- uninstall AVG
- uninstall Zone Alarm

Any free antivirus must be removed from the system and the tiles will resume working normally.

Answer (score 0):

My apps stopped working for no reason and with no error message. Then i went to the win app store and saw that 11 apps needed to be updated so i updated them and all are working now. thanks windows 4 telling me that i have to check on updates or my apps just stop working!